# laravel 4.2 and ignore global scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Model Eloquent called (TicketModel),

I add a global scope for take all tickets for a user , but sometimes , I want to use Ticket without this scope how can do it? how can ignore this scope

this is the model

```
<?php
class TicketModel extends Eloquent{

  public $timestamps = false;

    public static function boot()
    {
      static::addGlobalScope(new TicketScope);

    }


}

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;

class TicketScope implements ScopeInterface {

  public function apply(Builder $builder)
  {
      $builder->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id_user);
  }

  public function remove(Builder $builder){}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having a child class for the cases you need the scope?

Here's an example:

```
class TicketModel extends Eloquent
{
    // Your model stuff here
}

class UserTicketModel extends TicketModel
{
    public static function boot()
    {
      static::addGlobalScope(new TicketScope);
    }
}
```

The idea is not to ignore the scope sometimes, it's to use it when you need it.

If you really want the model without the scope to be the exception, let a `SimpleTicketModel` inherit from `TicketModel` and override `boot()` method so that it does not use the scope, like this:

```
class TicketModel extends Eloquent
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new TicketScope);
    }
}

class SimpleTicketModel extends TicketModel
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        // Do nothing else
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have more than 15 models , need to extends all classes

Comment: Extending classes is a one-time task. You need to say to your model, at a moment or another, that you don't need the scope. Another way is to call a method each time you want to ignore the scope (before model is instantiated), which means, possibly several times in one given script... Extending classes is not a big deal: once it's done, it's done. And your model has a name that means what it is. You might use it for Type Hinting, by the way.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 container allows [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#contextual-binding), which could be useful in your case... But Laravel 4.2... :/